# Does Switch current rating matters if its connected to ground wire

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, current-rating

I am designing a pcb with an SMD switch. Usually my circuit needs 200mA peak current. But I am putting a 25mA rated switch on the ground line. 
Now according to my knowledge if I was placing this switch on Positive supply then I should be using at least 250mA rated switch. But on ground line of the battery it shouldn't matter ?

Comment: The current will still flow through it, won't it?

Comment: @PlasmaHH your right for return path ? so I would need 250mA rated switch ?

Comment: Yes you would. Current is constant in a series circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ground wire is still part of the current loop so you need at least a 200mA rated switch.

That being said, don't put the switch on the ground line. If you do then parts of the circuit could still be "live" (at the potential of the power supply positive output with respect to ground) even when the switch is off. It would be much easier to accidentally short it out. Always put your power switch on the positive side of the circuit. This ensures that when the switch is in the off position the entire circuit is at 0V potential.